# heatmap Xaxis shifted down after arranging Yaxis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I created a heatmap and I arranged the y axis so each hour will be in the edge of a square.
It shifted the entire xaxis down, how can I upper it so it the ticks and labels of xaxis will be of the heatmap like the yaxis.
This is the code:

The making of the heatmap "frequencies of the days and hours- 2 hours resolution"

```
day_short_names = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']  #X axis 
hoursformat=['24:00','22:00','20:00','18:00','16:00','14:00','12:00','10:00','8:00','6:00','4:00','2:00','00:00'] #Y axis
pypl.figure(figsize = (20,15))
sb.heatmap(data = final, annot = True, cmap = 'mako', fmt = '000', xticklabels=day_short_names,yticklabels=hoursformat) #Formation of heatmap
pypl.yticks(nmp.arange(13),labels=hoursformat, va='center')
pypl.title('Listening Distribution to Spotify by Weekdays and Hours', fontsize = 25) #Title of heatmap
pypl.xlabel('Days of Week', fontsize = 15) #X axis title
pypl.ylabel('Hours (resolution of 2 hours)',fontsize = 15) #Y axis title
pypl.show() #showing the histogram graph
```

And this is the heatmap:

[image]

Comment: A side note: it is highly recommended to use the standard abbreviations to import pyplot (`as plt`), seaborn (`as sns`) and numpy (`as np`). That way it is much easier to map your situation to the documentation, tutorials and other stackoverflow posts. And it helps others to understand your code more rapidly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not expert enough to explain what happened, but I suspect it was because the y-axis ticks were set in the heatmap and then the y-axis ticks were set again. So I think we can remove the tick settings in the heatmap and add a new y-axis and x-axis.

```
sns.heatmap(data=final, annot=True, cmap='mako', fmt='000',cbar_kws={'shrink':0.95})
plt.yticks(np.arange(13), labels=hoursformat, va='center')
plt.xticks(np.arange(7)+0.5, labels=day_short_names, va='center')
```

[image]

Comment: The color bar was too large, so we adjusted it with `cbar_kws={}`. Remove it if you prefer to keep the default. If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer

Comment: the explanation should be part of the answer, not a comment. Even if it was a reply to another comment.

Comment: @Trenton McKinney I made the comment because I made the decision to add a setting that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: The problem is that comments are often deleted. The best way to preserve important information is to include it in the answer.

Comment: Note that the "bug" was setting `sns.heatmap(...., yticklabels=hoursformat)` when `hoursformat` has one entry too much. (It would be a nice extension to seaborn if it would automatically position such tick labels at the "logical" position.)

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for sharing useful information.